# Sass same code structure with different variables

Tags: css, sass

I am a new learner in sass, I have a question, if the code is the same but just using different variables, is it there any possible to avoid such repeating? Really appreciate your teach and help

```
&:hover {
            background-color: $primary;
            .link {
                color: $secondary;
            }
        }
```

```
&:hover {
            background-color: $secondary;
            .link {
                color: $primary;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can generate classes with mixins. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, create a [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) :**

```
@mixin mymixin($color1, $color2) {

    &:hover {
        background-color: $color1;

        .link {
            color: $color2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now use the mixin in your code using `@include`** :

```
@include mymixin($primary, $secondary);
```

With this, the *background-color* will be `$primary` and *color* will be `$secondary`. If you want to switch the colors, then interchange the position of variables.

```
@include mymixin($secondary, $primary);
```